# remove beyond the 2nd decimal in product weight woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

trying to remove numbers after the 2nd decimal on output of this code! Any ideas?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight', 'volumetric_calculations', 10, 2 );
    function volumetric_calculations( $weight, $product ) {
        $dim_weight = $product->get_length() * $product->get_width() * $product->get_height() / 5000;
        return $dim_weight > $weight ? $dim_weight : $weight;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return $dim_weight > $weight ? number_format($dim_weight, 2, '.', '') : number_format($weight, 2, '.', '');
```

OR

```
$output = $dim_weight > $weight ? $dim_weight : $weight;

return  number_format($output, 2, '.', '')
```

instead of

```
return $dim_weight > $weight ? $dim_weight : $weight;
```

Comment: Perfect! You are a savior!

Comment: Do you think that I could use echo to display the result in a field in backend product page?